# Tasks directory "grunt" not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to set up Grunt tasks but I get a Warning in the terminal

```
*>> Tasks directory "grunt" not found.

Warning: Task "undefined" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.*
```

I am learning one example of develomment NODE + Angular made by Sr. Carlos Santana in this Video 3:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juDeLmGjX8k

Grunt Version:

grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v1.0.1

Node Version: v5.1.0

**Gruntfile.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jscs');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-githooks');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
    grunt.loadTasks('grunt');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jscs:{
            options:{
                config: '.jscsrc',
                reporter: 'checkstyle'
            },
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'src/**/*.js',
                '!src/public/bower_components/**'
            ]
        },
        jshint:{
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: 'checkstyle'
            },
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'src/**/*.js',
                '!src/public/bower_components/**'
            ]
        },
        githooks: {
            all: {
                options:{
                    endMarker: ''
                },
                'pre-commit': 'analyze',
                'post-checkout': 'shell:gitLog',
                'post-commit': 'shell:gitLog',
                'post-merge': 'shell:gitLog shell:npmInstall'
            }
        },
        shell: {
            gitLog: {
                command: 'git log -1 > git-info.txt'
            },
            npmInstall: {
                command: 'npm install'
            },
            serverLogs: {
                command: 'pm2 logs'
            },
            serverStatus: {
                command: 'pm2 list'
            },
            serverStop: {
                command: 'pm2 kill'
            },
            serverDelete: {
                command: 'pm2 delete pm2.json'
            },
            serverStart:{
                command: 'pm2 start pm2.json'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['analyze']);
    grunt.registerTask('analyze', 'Validate code style' ['jshint', 'jscs']);
    grunt.registerTask('status', 'Shows status os node processes', ['shell:serverStatus']);
    grunt.registerTask('stop', 'Stop node processes', ['shell:serverStop']);
    grunt.registerTask('start', 'Start node processes', ['shell:serverStart']);
    grunt.registerTask('restart', 'Restart node processes', ['stop', 'start']);
    grunt.registerTask('logs', 'Tail logs for all pm2 processes', ['shell:serverLogs']);
};
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "StudioVictory",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm prune",
    "postinstall": "bower prune; bower install; grunt githooks"
  },
  "autor": "Carlos Santana",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/XXX/XX.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "latest",
    "lodash": "*",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "stylus": "latest",
    "nib": "latest",
    "js-yaml": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "latest",
    "grunt": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "latest",
    "grunt-githooks": "latest",
    "grunt-jscs": "latest",
    "grunt-npm-install": "latest",
    "grunt-shell": "latest"
  }
}
```

**Executing: grunt -v:**

```
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.

Registering "grunt-jscs" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-jscs\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-jscs\package.json...OK
Loading "jscs.js" tasks...OK
+ jscs

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-githooks" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-githooks\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-githooks\package.json...OK
Loading "githooks.js" tasks...OK
+ githooks

Registering "grunt-shell" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-shell\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory\node_modules\grunt-shell\package.json...OK
Loading "shell.js" tasks...OK
+ shell

Registering "grunt" tasks.
>> Tasks directory "grunt" not found.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ analyze, default, logs, restart, start, status, stop

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "analyze" task
Warning: Task "undefined" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Executing: grunt grunt**

```
C:\JACS\WampServer2.5\www\NODEJS\StudioVictory>grunt grunt
>> Tasks directory "grunt" not found.
Warning: Task "grunt" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: can you show the grunt task you are running and that task in your Gruntfile.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Grunt need one folder "grunt" by the line: grunt.loadTasks('grunt') in Gruntfile.js

Too in the folder "grunt" need one file "grunt-server.js"

See: https://github.com/CodeJobs/StudioVictory/tree/develop/grunt

This folder is created in Video 6.

Answer (score 0):

That means that grunt can't find the file you want to run. Check to see if you have a `Grunfile.js` in that directory. Is there a grunt module you have not installed? You can run `grunt -v` for more details.

I assume that your gruntfile has a tasks directory called grunt that you did not mean to call that. I would need to see more code to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your configuration and commands I think perhaps you havent any grunt command task like grunt.registerTask('default', ['analyze']); then how does grunt understand grunt grunt command. Either you have to create a task with grunt name or run just grunt from the root where your Gruntfile.js lying.

So Please just run grunt only it may be solve your issue. grunt only command find Gruntfile.js and execute task which is by default otherwise run the command with command name.

Comment: The problem was the missing folder  "grunt" .   Thank you.